# Adding target to selector

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to know how could I set target to my selector. I would like to make this call >>

```
    sortedArray = [views sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareWithUnit:)];
```

The problem is my `compareWithUnit` function is in `LogUnit` class. How should I tell the compiler to look for selector in `LogUnit` class ?

`views` array contains only `LogUnit` (UIViewControllers) objects, and i would like to sort my `views` array by `[LogUnit dayTime]` result.

```
- (NSComparisonResult) compareWithUnit:(LogUnit*) unit;
{
    return [[self dayTime] compare:[unit dayTime]];
}
```

Comment: Is `compareWithUnit` a static function within `LogUnit`?

Comment: Nop, but i can make it a static, what would that gain ?

Comment: If it were to be a static function i think you can test the following: 

`sortedArray = [views sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector([LogUnit compareWithUnit])];`

Comment: 1) views is an array of UIView/NSView objects (which one)? 2) From what class does LogUnit inherit?

Comment: Why would you want to sort views using a method that is in a different class? I guess the `compareWithUnit:` method compares the `LogUnit` receiver to another `LogUnit` object. How could such a method works with instances of another class?

Comment: I have updated my question with more details

Comment: If the objects in `views` are instances of `LogUnit` and `LogUnit` implements the `compareWithUnit:` method, then **everything is already fine**.

Comment: @Datenshi: If your views array contains LogUnit objects, and LogUnit defines a compareWithUnit: method, then it will work. Otherwise, you will get an crash. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake in code, both of you were right. Thank you all for your help. I'll accept sergio answer as it contains great information and helped me to understand selectors a little bit more. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [NSArray Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingSelector:):

> ```
>   - (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator
> ```
>
> The comparator message is sent to each object in the array and has as its single argument another object in the array.

So, `comparator` is expected to be a method of the objects that make up the array. When sorting, each object in the array will be sent that message.

If your `views` array contains `LogUnit` objects, and `LogUnit` defines a `compareWithUnit:` method, then it will work. Otherwise, you will get an crash.

There is no way to change this behavior, since it is hardcoded in `NSArray`.

By the way, there is no way to include the target in a selector definition, since a target is an object (i.e., an entity existing at runtime), while a selector is just the name of a message you sent to an object.

The idea of adding a class specification to a selector is also flawed for the same reason: a target is an object, not a class. Furthermore, when you send a message to an Obj-C object, you do that disregarding the class of the object, due to the dynamic nature of the language, so it would not help either.

Answer (score -1):

You can also create a selector from a string like:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"myMethod:");
```

Comment: The question is not about creating a selector. The question is about sorting objects using a selector.

Comment: I'm just trying to help mister angryface